# Semisimple vs ordinary trace of Frobenius on nearby cycles of affine flag variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, hecke-algebras

Let $G \rightarrow X$ be a parahoric group scheme over a curve, with parahoric level structure at $x_0$. Gaitsgory essentially showed that the nearby cycles functor $R\Psi$ takes perverse sheaves on the affine Grassmannian $Gr_G|_{X-x_0}$ to central perverse sheaves on the affine flag variety $Gr_G|_{x_0} = Fl_G$. This shows that the Frobenius trace function is central in the parahoric Hecke algebra, which is related to a conjecture of Kottwitz.

In the Shimura varieties literature, one usually deals with the semisimple trace of Frobenius instead, which should also be central in the parahoric Hecke algebra. So it seems that for a dominant coweight $\mu$ for $G$, indexing a perverse sheaf on $Gr_G$, we get *two* central functions in the parahoric Hecke algebra. What is the difference between them?

I would have thought that the ordinary trace of Frobenius gives the inverse under the Bernstein isomorphism, but it seems to me that this is also what's described in the Kottwitz Conjecture, which uses the semisimple trace of Frobenius. (For example, the Conjecture at the top of the second page of https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~ngo/nearby-cycle.pdf.)

Comment: The trace of Frobenius is associated to perverse sheaves with an action of Frobenius. Here you have perverse sheaves with an action of the Galois group of the local field of the point at the curve. To get a Frobenius trace function, there are a few different things you can do. The first is to take an arbitrary Frobenius lift and look at its trace. This should equal the semisimple trace of Frobenius in the unipotent case, and otherwise be undefined. The second is to take inertia cohomology and then take the trace of Frobenius. This will be $q-1$ times the semisimple trace, I think.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I have a perverse sheaf on the affine flag variety, admittedly with a monodromy action. Can't I just ignore the monodromy action and get a function on the rational points of the affine flag variety, i.e. G(K)/I, in the usual way that one associates a trace function to a perverse sheaf?

Comment: No. You associate a trace function to a perverse sheaf on a variety over a finite field. But the nearby cycles sheaf is not on a variety over a finite field. It's on the geometric special fiber over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Ah okay, in this setting it's "traditional" to denote by "nearby cycles" the $\mathbb{F}_q$-sheaf obtained by choosing a splitting of the Galois group, as in footnote 4 on p.8 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9912074.pdf. This sounds like the "first" thing you described in your first comment. It seems to me that I still have two distinct ways to produce central functions, and it makes sense to ask what the difference is. Perhaps your answer is that it depends on the choice of splitting?

Comment: It does depend on the choice of splitting unless the inertia action is unipotent, in which case it is equal to the semisimple trace.

Comment: I believe that in general, but in my case of interest, is it not the case that the trace function obtained is necessarily that specified by the Bernstein isomorphism, since it is true at the sheaf level that the map described is inverse to pushforward from the affine flag variety to the affine Grassmannian? In other words, the semisimple trace and honest trace functions (for any choice of splitting) coincide?

Comment: I think in your case they probably do. One just has to check that the inertia action is unipotent.